# How to add ribbon to application page by visual studio?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, ribbon, application-pages

I have created one application page and deployed that.But ribbon is not appearing at the same page? Any guesses or solution for this?

Comment: can you show your aspx code?

Comment: Is this 2010 or 2013?

Comment: @ali Sharepoint I just have created application page not written anything on page

Comment: @RobertLindgren Its Sharepoint 2013 and have used visual studio 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry im not being clear!:

there are two types of application pages!

the first contains no inherited masterpage and contains a reference to the .cs page but that is about it... it has head, body tags, looks somthing like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Meeting.aspx.cs" Inherits="meeting.Meeting" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the other what im trying to get to is different, it inherits from a masterpage on the server and it also inherits the page layouts and styles!

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Meeting.aspx.cs" Inherits="meeting.Meeting" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
Application Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitleInTitleArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" >
My Application Page
</asp:Content>
```

the first does not inherit any styles but the second does (layout, ribbon, masterpage,css), i use both methods in 2010 which is pritty much the same for 2013... first shows no ribbon, no master nothing. second on the other hand does show the default master, layouts associated with that master and its corresponding ribbon as its witin the master page ;)

here is a quick tut on creating the correct app page:

http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/application-page-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Saying all this i belive that you have created an application page (second example) but it still hasnt shown up.... you cold add it in by using this method:

http://www.vinodunny.com/blog/post/Application-Page-Ribbon-Dialogs-on-SharePoint-2010.aspx

sorry cant copy post here the method as its tooo long and detailed!

or here:

http://mysharepointt.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/sharepoint-ribbon-on-layout-pages.html

Comment: I have created the page as you stated in second page like http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/application-page-in-sharepoint-2013.html
but it does not showing ribbon as when we create a page in out of box.
I want something it should show me ribbon like out of box (Page,Browse,format etc)
I dont want to create my own ribbon element
please guide

Comment: its dependant on the maste page! do you have this within the aspx DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" , that will show the default ribbon!

Comment: i would like to know what do you want to show on the ribbon? by default nothing should be shown as there is not list no webpart ect! ribbon will add tabs accordingly dependant on what you have on the page aslong as your inheriting the default master!

Comment: as there is no ribbon, the end user can not modify the page. So for that purpose I wants to have ribbon there
And is not inheriting from master page.

Comment: it has to inherit from masterpage to get default ribbon from the aspx xaml!

Comment: no problem happy to help!!

Comment: @aliSharepoint: I'm using the first type application page(without inheriting a masterpage).How do I add ribbon to this type of page?

Comment: @george if you ask the question in the main area i can help as this question has been answered and dont want to clog up this thread!